# Rolle's Theorem on a derivative

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is differentiable with an $x$-intercept of $-3$ and that $f'(c) \leq 5$ for all values of $x$, how large can $f(2)$ possibly be?

Comment: So, f(2) could be equal or as high as y-value of 25 because its slope cannot be more than 5. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Try the mean value theorem: $(f(2)-f(0))/(2-0)=\dots$

Answer (score 0):

Use the mean value theorem instead. For some $c$ between $-3$ and $2$,

$$\frac{f(2)-f(-3)}{2-(-3)}=\frac{f(2)}{5}=f'(c)\leq5\implies f(2)\leq25$$

So $f(2)$ is at most $25$